# XAML Window Store Positioning of UI Element inside Datatemplate

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have created a Windows Store App with the default Hub Project, and on the first hubsection, I have an image as the background. I want to position some text at the bottom of the image to describe what the image is. However I am having trouble position the text inside the Hubsection.contenttemplate.

As you will be able to see from the code I have tried several things including trying to set the vertical alignment of both the grid and the individual text blocks, but neither seems to be working for me.

The code I currently have can be found below.

```
<HubSection Width="780">
            <HubSection.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Images/example_meal.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </HubSection.Background>
            <HubSection.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="80,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Primary Text" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}"  
                         TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" />

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="Secondary Text" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </HubSection.ContentTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Comment: Same problem here :(